# Prettier auto messed up the HTML banner on save

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

When I formatted my code with Prettier, via [Prettier's extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), it changed my comment/banner in such a way that now it isn't aligned.

[image]

Is there a way to configure prettier so it won't change the alignment as seen in the image above?

I'm hoping it kept my format like this :

```
<!-- ------------
/// ⭐️ Attributes
----------------- -->
```

---

## Codes

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <v-row v-for="(rule, index) in rules" :key="`rule-${index}`">
            <!-- ------------
        /// ⭐️ Attributes
        ----------------- -->
            <v-col md="4">
                <v-select dense outlined item-text="name" item-value="id" label="Attribute" :items="attributes" v-model="rule.attribute_id" @change="changeAttribute(index, rule.attribute_id)"></v-select>
            </v-col>

            <!-- ------------
        /// ⭐️ Operators
        ------------ -->
            <v-col md="3">
                <v-select outlined dense item-text="name" item-value="id" label="Operator" v-model="rule.operator_id" :items="rule.operators" @change="changeOperator(index, rule.attribute_id, rule.operator_id)"></v-select>
            </v-col>

            <!-- --------
        /// ⭐️ Values
        ------------- -->
            <v-col md="4">
                <v-row v-if="locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)">
                    <!-- -------------------------
                | City & Postal Code 
                ------------------------- -->

                    <v-col md="4" v-if="rule.attribute_id == 34">
                        <v-combobox :items="radiuses" v-model="rule.value_param" label="Radius" dense outlined></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col md="8" v-if="[36].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id != 15"> <v-text-field v-model="rule.value" :label="`Value (${locations.length})`" dense outlined append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)"></v-text-field> </v-col>

                    <!-- ----------------------
                | State/Province & Country 
                ------------------------- -->

                    <v-col md="8" v-if="[34, 35, 37].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id != 15">
                        <v-combobox :items="locations" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object v-model="rule.value" :label="`Value (${locations.length})`" dense outlined append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" @change="getLocations(rule.value, rule.attribute_id)"></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col md="8" v-if="[35, 37].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id == 15">
                        <v-combobox :items="locations" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object v-model="search" :label="`Search`" dense outlined append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" @change="getLocationsBasedOnValue(search, rule.attribute_id)" append-icon="add" @click:append="selectLocation(index, rule.value)"></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col md="12" v-if="[35, 37].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id == 15">
                        <v-combobox :items="inListLocations" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" v-model="rule.value" :label="`Added (${inListLocations.length})`" multiple chips clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" deletable-chips></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>

                    <!-- ------------------
                | Postal Code (In List)
                -------------------- -->

                    <v-col md="8" v-if="[36].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id == 15">
                        <v-text-field v-model="search" :label="`Postal Code`" dense outlined append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" append-icon="add" @click:append="selectLocation(index, rule.value)"></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col md="12" v-if="[36].includes(rule.attribute_id) && rule.operator_id == 15">
                        <v-combobox :items="inListLocations" item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" v-model="rule.value" :label="`Added (${inListLocations.length})`" multiple chips clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" deletable-chips></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>

                <v-row>
                    <v-col md="4" v-if="weatherIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)">
                        <v-combobox :items="days" v-model="rule.value_param" label="Day" dense outlined></v-combobox>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col md="8">
                        <v-menu v-if="rule.inputType == 'Date Range' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="rule.value" label="Values" append-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                            </template>
                            <v-date-picker range v-model="rule.value"></v-date-picker>
                        </v-menu>

                        <v-menu v-if="rule.inputType == 'Date Picker' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="rule.value" label="Values" append-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                            </template>
                            <v-date-picker v-model="rule.value"></v-date-picker>
                        </v-menu>

                        <v-select v-if="rule.inputType == 'Single Select' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" outlined dense item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object v-model="rule.value" label="Values" :items="rule.values" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" append-outer-icon="delete"></v-select>

                        <v-combobox v-if="rule.inputType == 'Multi Select' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" multiple outlined dense item-text="value_alias" item-value="value" return-object v-model="rule.value" label="Values" :items="rule.values" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)" append-outer-icon="delete"></v-combobox>

                        <v-text-field v-if="rule.inputType == 'Text' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" dense outlined required v-model="rule.value" :rules="form.rules.value" label="Values" clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)"></v-text-field>

                        <v-text-field v-if="rule.inputType == 'Init' && !locationIds.includes(rule.attribute_id)" readonly dense outlined required clearable v-model="rule.value" :rules="form.rules.value" label="Values" clear-icon="mdi-close-circle" append-outer-icon="delete" @click:append-outer="removeRuleDetail(index)"></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Conditions',
    props: {
        rules: Array
    },
    methods: {
        onClick() {
            console.log('%c ---', 'background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, blue, green, purple)')
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no way to answer this without know what you want it to look like after it is formatted?

Comment: Or before, if that after is what is shown. And we always prefer actual text over images of text. You should be able to copy and paste the ill-formatted code and place it between code fences...

Comment: Prettier [has some documentation of its configuration files](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)... Indeed, the [page you linked to has information about the same](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

Comment: @jD3V You're correct. I was hoping this keep align and not weirdly indented in like that on the top line! Do you get me ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I also uploaded my codes.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I looked at the links you share, and search for `HTML` ... not seeing any good settings there. Is it `prettier.htmlWhitespaceSensitivity ` ?

Comment: Setting that to `strict` would keep the whitespace the same no matter what you use. That might be good (it would not change the indentation of your comments), but it might be bad (it would not change any "bad indentation" you want to change). That's why I'd probably make an `attributes` component and use that, so that the code is self-documenting, and there's no need for multi-line comments, but I'm weird like that :).

Comment: Oh Yea, I see the comments are F'd up. I didn't knock u dwn but ill put u back to 0.

Comment: Yea I get what your saying.

Comment: It looks like what the "editor.wrappingIndent" setting does when set to "deep-indent"

Comment: Try setting it to `"editor.wrappingIndent": "same"` or try `"editor.wrappingIndent": "none"` and lemme know if that works.